# insert a new row getting some values from the same table

Tags: php, mysql

need to insert a new row inside `galls` table
`cnt` field should be copied from the same table - from a specific row (`id`)
`ind` field should be as a given variable - `$ind`
here is my try - getting syntax error

```
$id = 3;
$ind = 5;
$sq = "insert into galls(cnt, ind) values (select (cnt) from galls where id = :aid, :aind)";
$st = $db->prepare($sq);
$st->execute([
    ":aid" => $id,
    ":aind" => $ind
]);
```

Comment: Your sub query select statement should be wholy within brackets as the first paramter pair of the values statement. `values( (subquery), b, c)`

Comment: @Scuzzy - I tried - `values ((select (cnt) from galls where id = :aid), :aind)";` - syntax error again

Answer (score 0):

Use static values inside subquery.

```
$sq = "insert into galls(cnt, ind) values (select cnt, :aind from galls where id = :aid)";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a major syntax problem;
try this :

`insert into galls(cnt, ind) values ((select (cnt) from galls where id = :aid),:aind)`

btw, this is kinda odd for me. what're the columns of your table?

Comment: tried allready - see my answer to `Scuzzy`'s comment

Comment: @qadenza why you're not trying to do this separately? first select your cnt and then insert it into the table. it's easier to debug.